# Replace url if there is a certain word is written in a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, contains

I wanted to redirect the user on another url when I type a certain word in a textera.
I tried something but it doesn't work. I don't have a lot of knowledge in javascript and jquery so could someone check my code?

```
var url = "https://myURL";      

$('.button').on('click', function() {
    if ($("textarea").is(':contains("test")'))
        $(location).attr('href',url);
    else
        alert("Wrong word !");
});
```

Comment: try this `if ($("textarea").val() == "test")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this can search or indexOf method can be used as follows:

```js
var url = "https://myURL";      

$('.button').on('click', function() {
    var introString = $("#introduction").val();
    if(introString.indexOf("test") >= 0){
      $("#location").attr('href',url);
    }else{
      alert("Wrong word !");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="introduction"></textarea>
<button class="button">Submit</button>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="location">Browse</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = "https://myURL";  
$('.button').on('click', function() {
var textval = $("textarea").val();
if (textval.indexOf('test') !=-1) {
  window.open(url)
 } else {
alert("Wrong word !");
   }
});
```

Comment: Hi, Give a little more context on your answer.

Comment: thanks for taking time to answer. you might want to add why the OP's code did not work and why your's would work.

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation or details to your answer. While it might answer the question, just adding a piece of code as an answer, doesn't per say help OP or future community members understand the issue or the proposed solution.